# Edit some vertices manually without applying symmetry modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm a beginner.
1- I want to make a bunch of different symmetrical objects. These are gonna be my base meshes.
2- Then I want to make some duplicates of each one.
3- Then edit each new duplicate unsymmetrically.

The problem is that, after doing all these, I wanna go back and edit the base mesh symmetrically. If I use mirror modifier, I have to apply it for the third step. Is there a way I could do my manual edit without applying the modifier?

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to temporarily disable a modifier and 'manually editing it without applying the modifier'

But there is a method you can follow. Instead of applying a mirror modifier you can enable symmetry in edit mode.

by enabling either of these icons. [image]